# My MacBook Pro 13 inch keeps shutting down when battery is fully charged

Tags: laptop, battery

This is the crash report I got after it shut down:

> 10/14/14 8:30:54.177 PM MDCrashReportTool[320]:
>   320:2662400|CrashReportCopierAFC.m:-[CrashReportCopierAFC
>   copyAndProcessRemotePath:usingConnection:]| ERROR: Could not remove
>   remote path at ./DiagnosticLogs/security.log.20141013T190235Z.gz

Answer (score 0):

Can you please look in one of the following directories corresponding to your operating system version to find the crash report for your mac? The report your provided doesn't give us much information.

First, a quick shortcut to get to these directories is to copy and paste them. One way to do this is to click on the desktop and press CMD+SHIFT+G on your keyboard to get a dialogue box to navigate to these destinations. Otherwise, you can also click on the desktop and access "Library" by clicking on "Go" on the top navigation bar (after clicking the mac desktop) and holding the "alt" key.

Mac OSX 10.7/10.8/10.9
~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/

Mac OSX 10.6
~/ Library / Logs / DiagnosticReports

Here's some background notes:
I'm not very familiar with crash reporting tools on OS X, but my quick searches showed me that MDCrashReportTool is an executable for Windows rather than OS X. Perhaps this is a log from a different event. I've also found that the diagnostic log referenced at the tail end of that report is the same format as iOS devices when using the "idevicecrashreport." If the report you copied and pasted were from an iOS device, it would make sense why it isn't giving valuable information.